# Lagrange Problem: Error With System of Equations?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I'm taking an economics course this summer, and while multivariable calculus is not required (Calc 1/2 are), the professor will explain how to use a couple multivariable concepts.

The textbook introduces the Lagrange technique for F(x,y) with the constraint G(x,y) as $L\left(x,y\right)=F\left(x,y\right)+\lambda G\left(x,y,\lambda\right)$.

Then $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(L\left(x,y,\lambda \right)\right)\:\&\:\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(L\left(x,y,\lambda \right)\right)\:\&\frac{\partial \:\:}{\partial \:\:\lambda \:}\left(L\left(x,y,\lambda \:\right)\right)$.

Then set all 3 partial derivatives equal to zero and solve the system of equations.

I tried an example from Khan, and I cannot solve the system of equations, which makes me think I made an error somewhere. Here is my work so far:

$F\left(x,y\right)=x^2y\:with\:constraint\:\:x^2+y^2=1$

$L\left(x,y,\lambda \right)=x^2y\:+\:\lambda \:\left(x^2+y^2-1\right)$

$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(x^2y\:+\:\lambda \:\:\:\left(x^2+y^2-1\right)\right)=2yx+2λx$

$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:\:y}\left(x^2y\:+\:\lambda \:\left(x^2+y^2-1\right)\right)=x^2+2λy$

$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:\lambda \:\:}\left(x^2y\:+\:\lambda \:\left(x^2+y^2-1\right)\right)=x^2+y^2-1$

Now setting up a system of equations:

$2yx+2λx=0$

$x^2+2λy=0$

$x^2+y^2-1=0$

I don't believe this system of equations is solvable. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Following up on Paul's suggestion below:
With x=0, I get $x=0\:\&\:y=+2\:OR\:-2$

With $=−,\:I\:get\:the\:following\:potential\:pairs:\:\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},-\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\right),\left(-\sqrt{\:\frac{2}{3}},-\sqrt{\:\frac{1}{3}}\right),\left(\sqrt{\:\frac{2}{3}},\sqrt{\:\frac{1}{3}}\right),\left(-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}\:},\sqrt{\:\frac{1}{3}}\right)$

Now, the x=0 possibilites don't fit into my constraint.
The only values that fit into my constraint are $\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},-\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\right),\left(-\sqrt{\:\frac{2}{3}},-\sqrt{\:\frac{1}{3}}\right),\left(\sqrt{\:\frac{2}{3}},\sqrt{\:\frac{1}{3}}\right),\left(-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}\:},\sqrt{\:\frac{1}{3}}\right)$

At this point, I now plug these 4 potential pairs into the original function, and see which output is the highest?

Could someone confirm if my logic here is correct?
Thanks!

Comment: Factorize the first equation, which tells you $x = o$ or $y = -\lambda$. Follow each of these starting points through the other two equations separately. One line will give you no solution, but the other will.

Comment: I appreciate the response! I edited my post above. I THINK I solved it.

Comment: If $x=0$ then in second eqn $2\lambda y=0$ which implies $y=0$ or $\lambda = 0$. If $y=0$ that contradicts eqn 3 but $\lambda = 0$ does not. That leaves $y$ undetermined and since we started with $x=0$ that means in eqn 3 we can have $y = 1$ or $y = -1$ as another solution pair. Rest looks ok.

Comment: Thank you so much!